# SSD suddenly won't boot, blinking cursor

Tags: ssd

I had a power surge and my SSD won't boot anymore. It gets stuck with a blinking cursor right after startup

I'm still able to browse the drive when it's hooked up as a slave, so it does seem like the SSD itself is fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupt Master Boot Record - This means that your computer is no longer able to find the boot volume to load windows - If you have the recovery disk, or can boot into an external command prompt, you can fix this.

- If you have the recovery disk, insert this and boot to it - Once inside, select the Command Prompt option and enter the following command: Bootrec.exe/fixmbr - This should fix your MBR and allow your PC to boot properly.

If you don't have the Windows Disc, you can create a bootable flash drive with Partition Wizard, (Mini Tool Partition Wizard works well) and this will have a built in option to repair the MBR

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried repairing the MBR using Partition Wizard just now and the problem still occurs. Any more ideas I could try?

Comment: @fred Hmm, best bet is to use a Windows 7 Boot CD, if you have access to one. This will give you access to the bootrec.exe file and allow you to run a few other commands that are associated with the error you are receiving - Here is a guide that I have used in my profession to resolve your issue - http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html

Comment: Just to be sure, does all this still apply if I have Win 10 installed on the SSD? Are these tools forwards compatible?

Comment: @fred They should be, yes - Here is a link for fixing corrupt MBR on Win 10 - http://www.kapilarya.com/fix-windows-10-master-boot-record-corrupted